# Is there an infestor evolution in HOTS campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there an infestor evolution in HOTS campaign ?

I didnt evolve my infestors and I'm wondering If i missed the evolution mission.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The only zerg with evolution missions are those with mutations.  Specifically:

- Zergling
- Roach
- Baneling
- Hydralisk
- Mutalisk
- Swarm Host
- Ultralisk

If you receive the "Abathaur's Cookbook" achievement, that means you have completed all the evolution missions.

[image: achievement]